# Change ScrollView into HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have two layouts defined `mainactivity.xml` which is found in the `layout` folder, and another `mainactivity.xml` which is found in the `layout-port` folder. As you can probably tell one layout is for Landscape orientation and the other is for Portrait.

The issue I'm having is that in the Landscape layout I have a `ScrollView`, and in the Portrait layout it is a `HorizontalScrollView` with the same `id`. How do I change (in code) the ScrollView into a HorizontalScrollView when the orientation of the device changes?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a bools.xml file in res/values-land (and also one in res/values-port in which is_landscape should be set to false)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="is_landscape">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Then in your code you can check

```
if (getResources().getBool(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
     //setup horizontal scrollview
} else {
     //setup vertical scrollview
}
```

Although perhaps a better way is to use this library (so you don't have to code for two different ui components).

https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view

I'm using this in a current project and it works beautifully.

Answer (score -3):

In your scrollview define this property

android:orientation="horizontal" for landscape

android:orientation="vertical" for portrait

Comment: scrollview doesn't have an orientation property.

Comment: lol....i am using it in all my projects and you are saying it doesnt have orientation

Comment: Are you getting confused with Linearlayout? There is a ScrollView and there is a HorizontalScrollView. There is no orientation property on ScrollView.